# Object has no ID

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

When clicking on "save" (after creating a new instance) in the Django Admin Site I get an

```
AttributeError at /admin/bankaccount/bank_account/add/
'Bank_Account' object has no attribute 'id'
```

I did not create any IDs in the model. The tutorial says that IDs are auto-managed.
Any idea why I get this?

My Model:

```
class Bank_Account(models.Model):
   iban = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
   bic = models.CharField(max_length = 30)

def __init__(self):
    self.iban = 0
    self.bic = 0
```

My admin.py

```
from bankaccount.models import Bank_Account
from django.contrib import admin

admin.site.register(Bank_Account)
```

Comment: can you post how did you register the Bank_Account model to your admin ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume from your code sample that you've overridden the `__init__` (constructor) in your `Bank_Account` model. However you haven't called the super. Actually, the actions you take should be expressed as defaults in the model:

```
class BankAccount(models.Model):
    iban = models.CharField(max_length = 30, default="0")
    bic = models.CharField(max_length = 30, default="0")
```

which should work fine. However I'm not sure why you want those as defaults; I'd have thought that no default and `null=False, blank=False` is more appropriate in this case as a bank account will surely always have both IBAN and BIC. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding your domain problem there, though.

The key thing is: don't override constructors without ensuring you do all the work of the constructor in your superclass(es).

Comment: +1. You really don't want to do this in `__init__`, as it will ensure that `iban` and `bic` are **always** 0, even when you're loading an existing account from the database.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to call the parent constructor:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    models.Model.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    ...
```